# Ninject tells me a method is not implemented but its clearly there

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I realy don't know why Ninject throws this error since I have been using it for some time now.

It says I didn't implement a method but it's realy there.

Method 'GetApplicationLogEntries' in type 'FollowUp.Repository.Impl.ApplicationLogRepository' from assembly 'FollowUp.Repository.Impl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I made the smallest repro possible at https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6486369_1701716_00156

Can someone with ninject experience help me out please? Much appreciated.

Kind Regards, Tom

Comment: Please post your code here as part of your question - I don't think anyone is going to open a zip file from some external site to check out your code

Comment: @BrokenGlass the problem can only be reproduced if the types are across projects. I could explain it in text and soon a small repro would be asked. I took a few hours to isolate it to its minimum so I hope some people will care. Thanks for downloading the zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Ninject related problem. The exception tells you that the assembly could not be loaded by the .NET framework for any reason. Check the fusion log to get more information what happend.

A common reason for this type of exception is when you try to load an x86 assembly into a x64 process or the other way round.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for saving me! It's really appreciated

Comment: In my case an assembly was marked for Release rather than Debug.